# How to get Print Report Generation in Web Application

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, olap

Is there any reporting Engine like crystal report for generating easy reports from databases for web applications. 
I have html + css report on screen. I want to generate printer friendly report. I have looked into jsreport but it is paid. I am looking for easy solution for my web Application

Comment: You need only pdf reports?

Comment: no not just pdf but more

Comment: ReportLab is best option available. Please check its site, I think it will fulfill your requirements. http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf